# zsh filename globbling/substitution

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, glob

I am trying to create my first zsh completion script, in this case for the command netcfg.

Lame as it may sound I have stuck on the first hurdle, disclaimer, I know how to do this crudely, however I seek the "ZSH WAY" to do this.

I need to list the files in /etc/networking but only the files, not the directory component, so I do the following.

```
echo $(ls /etc/network.d/*(.))

/etc/network.d/ethernet-dhcp /etc/network.d/wireless-wpa-config
```

What I wanted was:

```
ethernet-dhcp wireless-wpa-config
```

So I try (excuse my naivity) :

```
echo ${(s/*\/)$(ls /etc/network.d/*(.))}

/etc/network.d/ethernet-dhcp /etc/network.d/wireless-wpa-config
```

It seems that this doesn't work, I'm sure there must be some clever way of doing this by splitting into an array and getting the last part but as I say, I'm complete noob at this.

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 7):

General note: There is no need to use *ls* to generate the filenames. You might as well use  `echo some*glob`. But if you want to protect the possible embedded newline characters even that is a bad idea. The first example below globs directly into an array to protect embedded newlines. The second one uses *printf* to generate NUL terminated data to accomplish the same thing without using a variable.

It is easy to do if you are willing to use a variable:

```
typeset -a entries
entries=(/etc/network.d/*(.)) # generate the list
echo ${entries#/etc/network.d/}  # strip the prefix from each one
```

You can also do it without a variable, but the extra stuff to isolate individual entries is a bit ugly:

```
# From the inside, to the outside:
# * glob the entries
#   * NUL terminate them into a single string
# * split at NUL
#   * strip the prefix from each one
echo ${${(0)"$(printf '%s\0' /etc/network.d/*(.))"}#/etc/network.d/}
```

Or, if you are going to use a subshell anyway (i.e. the command substitution in the previous example), just *cd* to the directory so it is not part of the glob expansion (plus, you do not have to repeat the directory name):

```
echo ${(0)"$(cd /etc/network.d && printf '%s\0' *(.))"}
```

Comment: Pity I've only got +1 to give. Three good options, all better than mine. :)

Answer (score 4):

Chris Johnsen's answer is full of useful information about zsh, however it doesn't mention the much simpler solution that works in this particular case:

```
echo /etc/network.d/*(:t)
```

This is using the `t` *history modifier* as a *glob qualifier*.

Comment: Nice solution, but that does not work properly with spaces in filenames.

Comment: @AntonK The globbing part works properly with arbitrary file names. The only part that has a problem is `echo`. In a real-world example, you wouldn't use `echo`, you'd pass the list to whatever command you want to process the files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions guys, having done yet more reading of ZSH and coming back to the problem a couple of days later, I think I've got a very terse solution which I would like to share for your benefit.

echo ${$(print /etc/network.d/*(.)):t}

Comment: Using a process substitution is a bad idea: it mangles file names containing spaces, it's more complex, and it's slower. Why not `echo /etc/network.d/*(.:t)` (or whatever real command you want instead of `echo`) which is simpler, robust and efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to seeing `basename(1)` stripping off directory components; also, you can use `echo /etc/network/*` to get the file listing without running the external `ls` program. (Running external programs can slow down completion more than you'd like; I didn't find a zsh-builtin for basename, but that doesn't mean that there isn't one.)

Here's something I hope will help:

> ```
> haig% for f in /etc/network/* ; do basename $f ; done
> if-down.d
> if-post-down.d
> if-pre-up.d
> if-up.d
> interfaces
> ```

Comment: The `${param#pattern}` parameter expansion is the way to go to remove prefixes. `${param%pattern}` to remove suffixes.